# Google Maps SDK for IOS, map blocked, and got "Maximum possible coords exceeded"

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

SDK version: 1.1.0.2080

On IOS 6

There are about 10~50 markers in the map, and refreshed with some same or different marker by user operation.

Every time the markers refreshed, the map will fitBounds animated and **[map clear]**.

When refreshed too many times(about 1000+ markers refreshed in total), I got 
`Maximum possible coords (10000) exceeded: 32768` in console and every thing blocked.

In GMSMapView.h, the doc of `clear` is:

> /**
>
> * Clears all markup that has been added to the map, including markers,
>
> * polylines and ground overlays.  This will not clear the visible location dot
>
> * or reset the current mapType.
>
> */
>
> - (void)clear;

This is my refresh function:

```
- (void)reloadMarkers:(NSMutableArray *)items fitbounds:(BOOL)fitbounds withVisibleRect:(CGRect)visibleRect
{
    [_map clear];
    if ([items count] == 0) {
        return;
    }
    if (fitbounds) {
        [self fitBounds:items withVisibleRect:visibleRect];
    }

    for (NSDictionary *item in items) {
        GMSMarkerOptions *options = [[GMSMarkerOptions alloc] init];
        options.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[item valueForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue], [[item valueForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue]);
        options.title = [item valueForKey:@"name"];
        options.userData = item;
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:[setting valueForKey:[item valueForKey:@"icon"]]];
        options.icon = img;

        [_map addMarkerWithOptions:options];
    }
}
```

I would apprecaiate any feedback/experience on how to resolve.

Comment: how do you save the coordinates ? Maybe you can show some codes .

Comment: I added my refresh function

Comment: Still trying to help: how many items in the `NSMutableArray` ? and in the `NSDictionary` ?

Comment: The `NSMutableArray` Created by network unit, has about 10 to 50 items in it. The `NSDictionary` has about 10 items. Does the warning in console means there are too many marks?

Comment: 50 x 10 = 500 ... still far from limit ( 10000 ). Not sure what does it cost the problem now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it might be a bug in the SDK, you could maybe raise an issue here:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Maps%20SDK%20for%20iOS%20-%20Bug

In the meantime maybe you could work around the issue by reusing the markers previously added (ie update their position, title, etc), instead of removing the old markers and adding new ones.

Answer (score 1):

Clear all markers that are not visible in screen, then you'll be fine.

Comment: I [map clear] every time, and I'm sure the map.markers.count == 0 after the clear

Comment: but each time you created too many markers. I don't believe a screen can view so many markers . Only place those visible . Those out of viewable areas , you can render them when they become visible

Comment: Maybe my description is not very clearly.There are 10~50 markers at the same time, and the old marker are cleared with`[map clear]` by refresh.